# perldoc not showing documentation for installed perl modules

Tags: perl, cpan, manpage, perldoc

Installing Perl modules from the Linux command line using the `cpan` command works fine, such as:

```
$ cpan [Module]
```

and after finishing I can see the module’s documentation via:

```
$ perldoc [Module]
```

But doing this via `cfengine`, which would just automate script the `cpan` command (in a *shellcommands:* list), the module gets installed, but `perldoc` will not work for it:

```
$ perldoc Text::Histogram
No documentation found for "Text::Histogram".*
```

However, invoking:

```
$ man Text::Histogram
```

will work just fine.

Setting a general environment variable for this (such as suggested by the `perldoc` man page) doesn't seem feasible as I observe the `.pm` files being placed in very diverse places.

Any hints about this?

Comment: Are you using a different user (than the cfengine,) when you try running a regular cpan command?

Comment: Do you have more than one `perl` on your system, but maybe only one `perldoc`? Try `perl $(which perldoc) The::Module`.

Comment: While I would like to know the answer to this one, if it works with `man`, what do you need `perldoc` for?  Just curious. Hmm... maybe if you had the [pmtools suite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/pmtools-1.10/) installed, I might ask about conflicting manpaths vs `@INC` paths.

Answer (score 3):

perldoc searches the Perl module include path (`@INC`).  If perldoc can't find it, perl can't find it.  Try `perl -wle 'use The::Module'` to see if perl can load it.  If it *can* find it, then something weird is going on.

What likely happened, if you installed a module via a third party program (even if it's just using the cpan client), is it got installed to a different location and/or a with a different perl than the one you're using on the command line.  There's a number of reasons for this, the three most likely are...

- It has a different `PATH` than you and found a different copy of `cpan` for a different `perl`.
- It's configured the `cpan` client differently to install to a different `PATH`.
- cpan is configured to install under the home directory, and it's running as a different user.

There is also the odd chance that the module has no documentation.

You can see what perldoc is doing to find the module with `perldoc -D The::Module` (this may be -v in older versions).